# MongoDB: Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, authentication, sha

I have inherited an ASP.NET project without all details how to run it. After installing the new MongoDB locally (according to the instruction), I see that error in the debug log:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, default installation was really... default, so I didn't have authentication enabled at all. With a little help from [Stampery Inc. Medium's author](https://medium.com/mongoaudit/how-to-enable-authentication-on-mongodb-b9e8a924efac), I have added the appropriate login data mentioned in the `appsettings.json` file of the connection string, and the exception don't return.

The message focused on an algorithm turned out to be misleading.